# Modify source code of a pre-built Package(external)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, so I am using a couple packages but the "output" that I get from the nodes isn't exactly what I need to work on.

I wanted to know -

1. If the source code of these pre-built packages can be modified, and if it can then how do we go about "updating" the package after that?
2. If I can't modify the source code, can I "manipulate" the output at the nodes *before* I forward it to other nodes if required?

Thank You!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56885/modify-source-code-of-a-pre-built-package(external)/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2013-03-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-03-03**:
What kind of manipulation do you need to do?

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-03**:
The coordinates that I get from the package are not along the axes I require. That is, Z direction is Y and X is negative Z.
So wanted to check if I can modify the code so that I get it right.

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-03**:
I'm sorry, I should've been clearer. Ignore the previous comment.
What I require is - X,Y and Z
What the package output is ('cause of the way it's in the code) - X, Z, (negative) Y
So I wanted to modify the code to change that.
(I hope you understood this time?)

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-03-03**:
Oh, that data format is wrong? Is it publishing a custom message type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**EDIT**: to answer both questions:

1. Check out sources into an overlay and modify that copy. See: http://answers.ros.org/question/47563/how-do-overlays-work/
2. Write another node that subscribes to the original topic, modifies each message as desired, and republishes it on a different topic name. You'll probably need to **remap** some topic names for that to work properly.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-03**:
I will give this a try. But I guess after modification, I just have to use "Make" inside that folder to compile it, right?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-04**:
It's a good idea to run **rosmake** first. Later, you can run **make**, to save build time.

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-04**:
I will try out the second way later and let you know. But modifying the code worked.
Note - I had to use "rosmake", "make" wasn't working. Will update once I figure out why. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I see what you mean. It might be easier to just set up a static transform publisher that puts your coordinates in the right frame, and then add it to your tf tree: http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher

You could also subscribe to the data, apply a transform manually, then republish it.

---

Originally posted by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) with karma: 452 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-04**:
Normal modification did work and it's pretty straightforward too. I will look into your procedure and let you know asap. Thank you!

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-20**:
@jj56 Modifying it directly worked like I said, but I also wish to add some code to convert a Quaternion set of rotations to Roll Pitch and Yaw. Unfortunately this isn't as easy as I expected it to be. (The source code of the package is in C++ but I am not at all familiar with this part of coding)

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-20**:
Any input regarding that?

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-03-20**:
@nemesis ROS has some methods for converting back and forth between rotation representations, have a look here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/geometry/RotationMethods

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-20**:
@jj56 - Thank you! That's what I am referring to. I use the getRPY code to try and access the RPY, but that gives me errors/"Note"s when I am trying to actually publish those values. I think since I am not familiar with such codes I am having a hard time figuring out how exactly to show the output.